# QGIS Finding Intersection of Points and Lines Layers in Electricity Grid

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, openstreetmap, infrastructure

I am new to GIS-related work and am currently using QGIS 3.34 for my research

I am trying to find the electricity grid topology and length of power lines between substations in the West of Sweden for performing power system analysis

I managed to get decent information from OSM (or OpenInfraMap to be exact) and mapped them in QGIS below as a start

[image]

From OSM, I have 104 Points layer for substation (black dots) and 845 Lines layer for power lines (blue lines).

Any way to combine both layers so that I can tell which power lines connect which substations?

I tried with the Intersection geoprocessing tools but didn't really work.

The end product that I am trying to make is this kind of table

| Line ID | Start Substation | End Substation | Length (in km) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | y | 3 |
| 2 | y | z | 4 |
| 3 | z | x | 5 |

Could anyone help with finding the appropriate tools or workaround?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @BERA They are from [OpenInfraMap](https://openinframap.org/) which is based on OSM and I extracted them using the Overpass Turbo API

Comment: I used this for extracting the substations `nwr["power" = "substation"];`, think nwr is node way relation for the layer type

Comment: @BERA I am not sure if this will show properly in comment, but here goes`[out:json][timeout:250];
// gather results for Västra Götaland
{{geocodeArea:Västra Götaland}}->.searchArea;
(
nwr["power" = "substation"](if:number(t["voltage"])>=100000)(area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;` note that I filter the voltage level of higher than 100kV in Västra Götaland

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151023/discussion-between-pandu-prianto-and-bera).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough sketch on how you can approach this:

1. Clean your lines. In your image they do not look like they are 845. You can do this using dissolve, either by id, name or something common for one power line. In case you dont have such information, you could dissolve all lines and then split the lines at the nearest substations and eventually also on power-line-crossings.
2. Extract start and end vertices for each line and use "Join Attributes By Nearest", limited to one result to gather informations from substations.
3. Since the extracted vertices will preserve the original line id's they come from you can now use an attribute join to get the information back to the initial lines.
4. To measure the length of lines you can use a simple field calculation with `$length`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will try this approach. The 845 lines are based on the Feature Count, although the vertices can come up to 12k points. I believe the dissolve and join attributes are under the Vector processing tool?